# BackboneJS Collection fetching in iOS but not in Android

Tags: android, cordova, backbone.js

I have a phonegap webapp running on BackboneJS. It fetches JSON from a backend running in localhost:3000.

The collection fetches correctly in the browser and in iOS within the emulator. However android does not work!

my /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My config.xml file

```
<access origin="*" />
```

any idea why it does not work in Android?
When i inspect the response all i have is response.statusText saying "error"

Answer (score 0):

Well after spending some time looking around i tried using a real IP address to fetch the JSON (I was using localhost:3000 before) and it now works.

It's quite weird that it was working on iOS and not on Android